# How fetch all calling option available like IOS Native Call app provide in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I need all possible calling option same as IOS native Call.

I don't want `NSURL(string: "tel://\(busPhone)")`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look up what URL each app (Skype, ...) uses to initiate calls.

Then use [`canOpenURL(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl) to check which of these calling apps are installed.

Comment: So, I need to check the URL scheme for each app. If a new app is launched that supports VOIP calls, I need to check the URL scheme for that new app and after adding a new app's URL scheme, I need to update my app in App Store every time.

Comment: Yes.  There is no universal calling control provided by iOS

Comment: There are lots of apps which is support VOIP calls and we can't handle them all. Apple contact App working fine with all apps. I check with Skype, Viber, Telegram, Whatsapp, and Google Duo.

Comment: @MayurBoda indeed you need to add the URL scheme for new apps.  Updating the app is one way to do this, reading a resource file from a server is another.

Comment: @MayurBoda Install an obscure/unknown VoIP app and check if it appears as calling option in Apple's apps.